# Trying to set up a simple nginx ruby on rails development. How do I run the app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, virtualbox, vagrant

I am really struggling to understand this.

I have used PHP / Apache all my life but I just need to have a very basic setup of a Ruby on Rails app on an Nginx server for development.

I have set up an Ubuntu 12.04 server with Vagrant / VirtualBox.

I can see in the web browser the "Welcome to nginx!" message and there's a Ruby on Rails app installed on the server (tested with someone else and working on there server).

The Ruby on Rails application is in an /app/ folder and with these folders:

```
- assets
- controllers
- helpers
- mailers
- models
- observers
- uploaders
- views
```

Now, all I need to do is run the thing. Where is my index file?

Are there any other folders I should take note of? There's nothing I can see.

I've tried configuring sites-enabled but none of it makes sense. Surely it should be a simple case of getting my-domain.com to display the index file. Simple, surely? Which file in the /app/ folder am I trying to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For development you can use the built-in web-server with `rails s` in your project folder. It will runs your RoR app on 0.0.0.0:3000. Port can be changed with `-p` (`rails s -p 80`).

Comment: The binding can also be changed with `-b`, for example `-b 127.0.0.1`.

Answer (score 0):

Read this [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu) to running rails on `nginx` using `passenger`:

> Once Ruby on Rails is installed, go ahead and install passenger.
>
> ```
> gem install passenger
> ```

...

> Set the root to the public directory of your new rails project. Your
>   config should then look something like this:
>
> ```
> server { 
> listen 80; 
> server_name example.com; 
> passenger_enabled on; 
> root /var/www/my_awesome_rails_app/public; 
> }
> ```

(Don't forget the `/public` after the rails root location!)